# How to open gedit , nautilus , gnome commander using sudo command?

Tags: x11, sudo, root

Whenever I open gedit,nautilus and other files in terminal using sudo command, I get the error -->

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:22993): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

The `startx` command and changing the gnome theme(example Wayland,Xorg) does not work too with this error

Answer (score -1):

The solution for you would be to simply use `gnomesu` instead of `sudo`. As written [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/453089-Using-gedit-as-root-quot-Gtk-WARNING-**-cannot-open-display-quot),

> it is a normal security issue. You have a multi user system where many users can login, either local or remote, in a GUI session. What if other logged in people would be able to open windows on your desktop without your allowance? Inconvenient at least, but the would also be able to create a window such that thay could read all your keyboard typing including your bank accounts. Thus the need for giving allowance with `xhost`.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, however this is the most simple way so I'd suggest you doing this. If you want to use the normal sudo(for I don't know what reason) anyway, you can do a change stated in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614387/gksu-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-0) question.

> Try running `xhost +localhost` in your terminal, and then running the
>   sudo again. This lets all users on your system (i.e. root) open
>   windows on your screen. Make sure to use 
>   `+localhost` and not simply `+`,
>   as it's more secure to allow connections from only localhost than from
>   anywhere.
>
> To make this permanent, edit the ~/.xinitrc file like this:
>
> Run `gedit ~/.xinitrc`
>
> Edit the file to look like this (it should be empty at the start):

```
#!/bin/bash 
xhost +localhost &
```

> Now save the file, log out and log in. Now everything should run just fine with sudo.

Comment: `xhost +localhost` is not a good idea, and adding it to `.xinitrc` does not work for most users because most users don't run `startx`.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: As explained in the first part of your answer, it allows any process running as any user on your machine to interact with the programs you run.

Comment: But only from your localhost so as long as it is for personal use there shouldn't be any problem.